# Cannot import non-existent remote object, but it exists

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to import a policy attachment to an IAM role, but I can't attach user managed roles for some reason.

This policy is already created and already attached, I just need to import the attachment into the terraform state. The policy was imported successfully, only the policy attachment is not working.

I'm using Terraform version **1.1.4** and AWS provider version **4.56.0**.

My code:

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "my-attachment" {
  role       = "my-role"
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::1234567890123:policy/my-policy"
}


resource "aws_iam_policy" "my-policy" {
  name        = "my-policy"
  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Action = [
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:DescribeLogStreams"
        ]
        Effect   = "Allow"
        Resource = "*"
      },
    ]
  })
}
```

I'll let here some tries and some errors I faced, the first try I did following the [terraform documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_role_policy_attachment).

> IAM role policy attachments can be imported using the **role name** and **policy arn** separated by `/`.

Here is:

`terraform import aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.my-attachment my-role/arn:aws:iam::1234567890123:policy/my-policy` :

```
│ Error: Cannot import non-existent remote object
│ 
│ While attempting to import an existing object to "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.my-attachment", the provider detected that no object
│ exists with the given id. Only pre-existing objects can be imported; check that the id is correct and that it is associated with the
│ provider's configured region or endpoint, or use "terraform apply" to create a new remote object for this resource.
╵
```

I tried to isolate role name from policy arn using `" "` and `{ }`, no success.

Other tries:

`terraform import aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.my-attachment arn:aws:iam::1234567890123:policy/my-policy` :

```
╷
│ Error: reading IAM Role Managed Policy Attachment (arn:aws:iam::1234567890123:policy/my-policy): ValidationError: The specified value for roleName is invalid. It must contain only alphanumeric characters and/or the following: +=,.@_-
│   status code: 400, request id: xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx
│
```

`terraform import aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.my-attachment my-role` :

```
│ Error: unexpected format of ID ("my-role"), expected <role-name>/<policy_arn>
```

I also tried to import an AWS managed policy, it worked.

`terraform import aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.test my-role/arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess`

```
Acquiring state lock. This may take a few moments...
aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.test: Importing from ID "my-role/arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess"...
aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.test: Import prepared!
  Prepared aws_iam_role_policy_attachment for import
aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.test: Refreshing state... [id=my-role-arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess]

Import successful!

The resources that were imported are shown above. These resources are now in
your Terraform state and will henceforth be managed by Terraform.
```

I see in my bash history I was able to import the `aws_iam_role_policy_attachment` in the past, I have no idea what is happening this time.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out why it wasn't working.

I created an **inline policy** instead of a regular policy.

Inline policies are vinculated to the role and it isn't available to be used for other roles/users. It is a exclusive resource for a role.

I solved it replacing the inline policy with a regular one.